# Не работает инструкция switch

Tags: c#

Что не так? Ошибка - Unmatched

```
using System.Windows.Forms;  
class TestSwith {
    public static void Main() {  
        int i;  
        for (i = 0; i != 5; i++)  
            switch (i) {  
                case 19:  
                    MessageBox.Show((string) i, "Message:");  
                    break;  
                case 2:  
                    MessageBox.Show((string) i, "Message:");  
                    break;  
                default:  
                    MessageBox.Show("default", "Message:");  
                    break;

            }  
      }
```

}

Comment: у меня никакой ошибки нету, вот вполне очевидный вывод:

    Message: 
    default 

    Message: 
    default 

    Message: 
    2 

    Message: 
    default 

    Message: 
    default

Comment: Стало быть IDE глючит, потому что объявить переменную типа byte bOne; тоже считается ошибкой...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно, никого не смутил это участок:

```
for (i = 0; i != 5; i++)   // variable i in 0..4
            switch (i) {  
                case 19:   // WTF !?
                    MessageBox.Show((string) i, "Message:");  
                    break;  
                case 2:  
                    MessageBox.Show((string) i, "Message:");  
                    break;  
                default:  
                    MessageBox.Show("default", "Message:");  
                    break;

            }  
      }
```

Ну это так, логику просто хочется понять...да не могу =)

---

И ошибка "Unmatched", скорее всего, не в этом классе. Перепроверьте.

Comment: почему "WTF"? вполне нормальная демонстрация невыполнимых кейсов